# React Native: How to add a vector icon if it's not in the directory?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons, vector-icons

I use vector icons in my React Native app, and I find the available ones in [this directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/). I need to add an icon that look this [this](https://www.iconbolt.com/iconsets/ionicons-outline/filter-circle), but there isn't one in the directory. If I download the svg file at that [link](https://www.iconbolt.com/iconsets/ionicons-outline/filter-circle), is there a way to add it to my app? Or is there a different recommended way to add vector icons that aren't in the [directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use 2 libs: [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer) and [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg)

1. Download the svg you want, save it in a folder inside your of project
2. Install **react-native-svg and react-native-transformer**:

```
 yarn add react-native-svg-transformer react-native-svg
```

or

```
 npm install react-native-svg react-native-svg
```

3. Now, you need configure your project, the babel:
   Go to the file **metro.config.js** in the root of your project and merge the contentswith this config (create the file if it does not exist already):
4. Case use React-Native CLI:

```js
 const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");
 
 module.exports = (async () => {
   const {
     resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
   } = await getDefaultConfig();
   return {
     transformer: {
       babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
     },
     resolver: {
       assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
       sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
     }
   };
 })();
```

5. Case use Expo:

```js
  // Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
  const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
  
  module.exports = (async () => {
      const {
        resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
      } = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
      return {
        transformer: {
          babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
        },
        resolver: {
          assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
          sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
        }
      };
    })();
```

6. Now just import the svg that you downloaded in your component as React Component and use:

```js
   import TransparentPokeball from '../../assets/icons/transparent-pokeball.svg';
   ...
 
  <TransparentPokeball
     fill="#000000"
     width={45}
     height={45}
  />
```

Note:

- Case use Typescript, you need add type for svg files as like png files, json files...
- Just create a folder in your project's src with name @types, in it, create another folder with name svg, inside that svg folder, create a file called index.d.ts with the code below:

  ```
     declare module "*.svg" {
         import React from 'react';
         import { SvgProps } from 'react-native-svg';
         const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
         export default content;
     }
  ```

In case there is any doubt, just consult the links of the libraries I sent. they have everything I mentioned above documented.